# Shake effect that doesn't affect other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to use the shake effect on a div without affecting the other elements around it? My first thought was to change the z-index of the div I was using the effect on, but this changed nothing.

I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33ad9sck/) to show what I mean.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.shake').on('click', function(){
        var decider = Math.round(Math.random() * 5) + 1
        $('.box:nth-child(' + decider + ')').effect('shake');
        decider = null;
    })
})
```

Comment: You can do this in CSS - there's the [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library you can use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your issue using jQuery UI effect, you can set as CSS rule:

```
.ui-effects-wrapper {    
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33ad9sck/2/)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit `no need to shout :)` My bad ***:)***

Answer (score 2):

When you run the animation, jQuery creates an element with the class `ui-effects-wrapper`. Set it's CSS to `display: inline-block`. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33ad9sck/3/).